# Image Table can be associated with two different tables

Tags: postgresql

I am creating a front end to a bioinformatics platform and I have to tables `Experiment` and `Sample`.  An `Experiment` can consist of many individual samples, e.g. a one-to-many relationship.

Experiment table relation looks like:
`(id, experiment_name, additional_columns)`

Sample table relation looks like:
`(id, sample_name, experiment_id, additional_columns)`

Now, I want to create a table for `Images` that would be associated with an S3 uri and some metadata about an image; however, the images can be associated with either the `Experiment` OR the `Sample`. I could do something like,

```
CREATE TABLE images (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    s3_image_uri text NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (experiment_id) REFERENCES experiment (id),
        FOREIGN KEY (sample_id) REFERENCES sample (id),
    CONSTRAINT images_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT images_image_url_key UNIQUE (image_url),
);
```

The downside of this design is that in the future I could add additional tables that could have images associated with them as well.

How can I generalize this design so that I don't have to add an FK for each table that has an image association?

Comment: I think so! So Experiment and Sample correspond to Question and Answer respectively and the Comments table is the Image table in my example; what is the Post table (from a name perspective)?

Comment: Ah, naming things... one of the hardest problems in Computer Science! Especially hard because you don't know yet what other types of entities will be added in the future. How about `EntityWithImages`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the most correct design would be to create the `image` table without foreign keys, and for the rest of the tables that are associated with the `image` table, implement the `OneToMany` or `ManyToOne` association.

Assuming that your `experiment` table can contain many images, then you need to implement the OneToMany association by creating an additional table `experiment_images`

```
  CREATE TABLE experiment (
       id INT NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (id)
  ); 
  CREATE TABLE image (
       id INT NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (id)
 ); 

 CREATE TABLE experiment_images (
      experiment_id int NOT NULL,
      image_id int NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (experiment_id, image_id),
      CONSTRAINT fk_experiment FOREIGN KEY(experiment_id) REFERENCES experiment(id),
      CONSTRAINT fk_image FOREIGN KEY(image_id) REFERENCES image(id)
 );
```

This will keep the `image` table from changing in the future. if you have additional tables.

Demo in  [sqldaddy](https://sqldaddy.io/a99308ec)